# Updating previously migrated TFS 2013 -> TFS2015 database

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have TFS 2013 update 5 installed in a virtual environment (VMWare ESXi 5.5) and I wanted to test upgrading to TFS 2015. I cloned the VM and changed the TFS ID. After a long battle with sharepoint (everything is running on the same VM at this point, App-Tier, Data-Tier, and Sharepoint Foundation 2013) I got everything working again on the clone at TFS 2013 version. I then performed an in-place upgrade on this clone to upgrade it to 2015 and it worked perfectly.

Now what I want to do is take the most recent backup of the TFS2013 original server databases and move that to the already upgraded TFS2015 server. I have not been able to do this and successfully trigger "re-upgrading" of the database.

- What databases should I restore to the clone "TFS2015" server (should I overwrite Tfs_configuration at this point, for example)?
- What steps should I perform after restoring the latest backup from the TFS2013 data-tier to the TFS2015 data-tier to trigger an upgrade of the database?

Comment: You should just do a full migration. Just unconfigure the application tier, restore all databases, run the remapdb's commandlines and reconfigure the apptier. Or simply in-place upgrade the 2013 machine.

Comment: See these checklists and supported upgrade/migration scenario's: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/08/14/team-foundation-server-2015-upgrade-planning.aspx